# Print iFrame with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have followed unlimited examples on how to print an iframe with jQuery, but no matter what I attempt, it doesn't work.

I have a page that has a "Print" button so users can print an iframe. So I followed examples and past experiences with jQuery and came up with this:

```
$('#printButton').click(function() {        
    window.frames["frameright"].focus();
    window.frames["frameright"].print();
});
```

Accordingly, my iframe is

```
<iframe seamless="seamless" id="frameright" name="frameright" src="url..."></iframe>
```

but when I click the "Print" button, nothing occurs.

Anyone kind enough to push me in the right direction?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831147/printing-contents-of-a-dynamically-created-iframe-from-parent-window for potential solutions.

Comment: your code works fine for me for same domain iframe...

Comment: @Sandeep: the src i'm using is not on the same domain. is that the problem?

Comment: yes pattmorter that is the problem. when i tried changing the domain of the iframe its throwing a security exception and not allowing me to open the print dialogue even.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use jQuery for this.

Simply use:

```
function printiframe() {
        window.frames["frameright"].focus();
        window.frames["frameright"].print();
}
```

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I can tell you this doesn't work on any browser except Chrome. It's also exactly the answer the OP used.

Comment: You copied your answer from exactly the same page where the question was asked LOL