# trying to print iframe content but print the whole page instead

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I've iframe that i created dynamically  in my html page and print button with event on click 
to print iframe's content 
but unfortunately it prints the whole page instead 
but after long search 
I've found some solutions like focus on iframe before fire print event 
but it seems doesn't work on IE and MS Edge 
it works in Chrome 
the only solution that works with me is to open new window and copy iframe outerhtml in it and fire print event after the content loaded in new window 
then close the new window immediately after the user take an action to print or cancel 
but this solution doesn't look user friendly 
so does it there any solution to print iframe content in IE and Edge

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>IFrame Printing Issue</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var g_iFrame;

  function onLoad()
  { 
     g_iFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
     g_iFrame.id = "testFrame";
     var style = g_iFrame.style;
     style.border = "1px solid black";
     style.width = "300px";
     style.height = "200px";

     document.body.appendChild(g_iFrame);
  }

  function setIFrameSrc()
  {
     g_iFrame.src = "Test.htm";
  }

  function printIFrameContent()
  {
  window.frames["testFrame"].contentWindow.focus();
  window.frames.testFrame.contentWindow.print();
  }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="onLoad();">
<button type="button" onclick="setIFrameSrc();">Set IFrame Src</button> 
 <br /> 
<button type="button" onclick="printIFrameContent();">Print IFrameContent</button>
<br /> 

 <div style="border: 1px solid black; width: 300px; height: 200px;">
  This is to test printing the content of an IFrame whose src is set dynamically.
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may first check if the user agent is IE:

```
function printIFrameContent()
{      
  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
  var msie = ua.indexOf ("MSIE ");
  var iframe = document.getElementById("testFrame");

  if (msie > 0) {
      iframe.contentWindow.document.execCommand('print', false, null);
  } else {
      iframe.contentWindow.print();
  }
}
```

Referred a similar answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19639241/1500851

Comment: this method doesn't seem capable to identify IE 
when I opened the test from IE the value of msie stays -1

Comment: You can use the strings `"Trident"` to check for IE and `"Edge"` for Edge